# Angularjs resource handling response & custom methods

Tags: angularjs, resources

Is it possible within the AuthService to handle the response and set the session with the SessionService?

I doing it in the controller right now with the success callback but I'm still new to Angularjs and trying to understand how to customize a resource.

I'm using Angularjs 1.1.5

```
app.factory('AuthService', ['$resource', 'SessionService',
function($resource, SessionService) {

    return $resource(
        '/api/v1/auth/:action',
        {action:'@action'},
        {
            login: {
                method:'POST',
                params: {
                    action: 'login'
                }
            },
            logout: {
                method:'GET',
                params: {
                    action: 'logout'
                }
            }
        }
    );
}
]);

app.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'AuthService', 'SessionService' function LoginCtrl($scope, $location, AuthService, SessionService) {

$scope.credentials = { email: "", password: ""};

$scope.login = function() {
    AuthService.login($scope.credentials).success(function() {
        SessionService.set('authenticated', true);
        $location.path('/home');
    });
}
}]);

app.factory("SessionService", function() {
 return {
  get: function(key) {
   return sessionStorage.getItem(key);
  },
  set: function(key, val) {
   return sessionStorage.setItem(key, val);
  },
  unset: function(key) {
   return sessionStorage.removeItem(key);
  }
 }
});
```

Comment: can't understand what your question mean. Can you post the code of the  controller ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that $resource is the appropriate abstraction to use here. I think it would be much simpler to implement your AuthService using plain $http. Just implement login and logout as normal function, then you can feel free to do whatever you want there. You should also make sure you return the promise, that way whoever calls login() or logout() can still do .then() on it if they need to do additional things after login. Here's an example:

```
app.factory('AuthService', ['$http', '$location' 'SessionService',
function($http, $location, SessionService) {
     var baseUrl = '/api/v1/auth/';

     function onLoginSuccess(data){
            SessionService.set('authenticated', true);
            $location.path('/home');
     }

     function onLoginFailure(error){
       SessionService.unset('authenticated');
       $location.path('/login');
     }


    return {
      login: function(credentials){
          return $http.post(baseUrl+'login', credential).then(onLoginSuccess, onLoginFailure);
      }

      logout: function(){
          return $http.get(baseUrl+'logout');
      }
    };

app.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', 'AuthService', function LoginCtrl($scope, AuthService) {
    $scope.credentials = { email: "", password: ""};
    $scope.login = function() {
        AuthService.login($scope.credentials);      
    }
}]);

app.factory("SessionService", function() {
 return {
  get: function(key) {
   return sessionStorage.getItem(key);
  },
  set: function(key, val) {
   return sessionStorage.setItem(key, val);
  },
  unset: function(key) {
   return sessionStorage.removeItem(key);
  }
 }
});
```

Comment: This is what I'm doing right now. Can I have the same logic with a resource?

Comment: There's no real value or reason to use resource in your case. Is there a particular reason you really want to use $resource ?

Comment: You could add additional methods to your resource before returning it from your AuthService, but then you would be returning both a high and low level api from the service. The way I do it in my answer is return an object with just high level login/logout methods, therefore hiding the underlying implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Your server side script on path /api/v1/auth/login should return a result to indicate that the login is successfully granted or not.

For example, If the log in is granted, then `/api/v1/auth/login` returns the success response `200`.
If the login is denied, then `/api/v1/auth/login` returns the bad request response (failure) `400`.

If with this condition, your code should be written as followed,

```
app.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'AuthService', 'SessionService'
function LoginCtrl($scope, $location, AuthService, SessionService) {
    $scope.credentials = { email: "", password: ""};
    $scope.login = function() {
    AuthService.login($scope.credentials, function(data) { //Success callback
        SessionService.set('authenticated', true);
        $location.path('/home');
    }, function(error){ //Failure callback
        SessionService.unset('authenticated');
        $location.path('/login');
    });
}
}]);
```